# A very simple IIS7 redirect to different path

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I have had a site at www.mysite.com/myfolder/ for years.  I have developed a new version and want to just remove the /myfolder so that the site serves all pages from www.mysite.com.

Example:  www.mysite.com/myfolder/mypage.htm will be permanently redirected to www.mysite.com/mypage.htm

How do I configure this using the URL Rewrite module in IIS7?  I start with a blank rule, but then get lost.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either use the IIS Management UI or edit the web.config directly. With a section in web.config that looks like this, you will redirect *everything* (images as well), which might be want you want.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^myfolder/(.*)" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

If you use the Management tool, you add an empty rule, give it a name, add ^myfolder/(.*) as the pattern, select *Redirect* as action type, add {R:1} as target URL and select 301 as *redirect type*.

This is supposed to be permanent, that's why you should use a 301 redirect (for SEO purposes and so on).